# Transaction succeed even if require() is false

Tags: contract-development, mist, contract-debugging

I wrote a contract and I have a require() in my callback function saying:

```
require(msg.value >= 1 / buyPrice);
```

where buyPrice = 100;

When I test it in Remix and I send 0.0001 ETH it works, transaction fails. But when I test on Ropsten network and I send the same amount I receive ethers, how come?

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.6.0;

contract owned {
    address public owner;
    address constant public ledger = 0xd7b4754A023B92F811EF98b2bd1cD8d531905E5a;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) public; }

contract MyCoin {
    // Public variables of the token
    string public name = "MyCoin";
    string public symbol = "XYZ";
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    uint256 initialSupply = 50000000;

    // This creates an array with all balances
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    // This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    // This notifies clients about the amount burnt
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     */
    constructor() public {
        totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  // Update total supply with the decimal amount
        balanceOf[this] = totalSupply;                // Give the creator all initial tokens
        //name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        //symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
    }

    /**
     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
     */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require(_to != 0x0);
        // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        // Check for overflows
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
        // Save this for an assertion in the future
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        // Add the same to the recipient
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }


    /**
     * Transfer tokens from other address
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` in behalf of `_from`
     *
     * @param _from The address of the sender
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address and notify
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
     */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        public
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens from other account
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
     *
     * @param _from the address of the sender
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
        totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
        Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }
}

/******************************************/
/*       ADVANCED TOKEN STARTS HERE       */
/******************************************/

contract MyAdvancedToken is owned, MyCoin {

    uint256 public sellPrice = 500;
    uint256 public buyPrice = 500;
    uint256 private endTime = 1517788799; //4 February 2018 23:59:59

    uint256 private phaseOneStart = 1513814400; //21.12.2017 00:00:00
    uint256 private phaseOneEnd = 1514764799; //31.12.2017 23:59:59

    uint256 private phaseTwoStart = 1514764800; //1.1.2018 00:00:00
    uint256 private phaseTwoEnd = 1516147199; //16.1.2018 23:59:59

    uint256 private xmasStart = 1514160000; //25.12.2017 00:00:00
    uint256 private xmasEnd = 1514246399;   //25.12.2017 23:59:59
    uint256 private newyearStart = 1514764800;  //1.1.2018 00:00:00
    uint256 private newyearEnd = 1514851199;    //1.1.2018 23:59:59

    mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;

    /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event FrozenFunds(address target, bool frozen);

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    constructor() MyCoin() public {}

    /* Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        require (_to != 0x0);                               // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require (balanceOf[_from] > _value);                // Check if the sender has enough
        require (balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
        require(!frozenAccount[_from]);                     // Check if sender is frozen
        require(!frozenAccount[_to]);                       // Check if recipient is frozen
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                           // Add the same to the recipient
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        ledger.transfer(this.balance);                       //send balance to the owner
    }

    /// @notice Create `mintedAmount` tokens and send it to `target`
    /// @param target Address to receive the tokens
    /// @param mintedAmount the amount of tokens it will receive
    function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner public {
        balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
        totalSupply += mintedAmount;
        Transfer(0, this, mintedAmount);
        Transfer(this, target, mintedAmount);
    }

    /// @notice `freeze? Prevent | Allow` `target` from sending & receiving tokens
    /// @param target Address to be frozen
    /// @param freeze either to freeze it or not
    function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) onlyOwner public {
        frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
        FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
    }

    /// @notice Allow users to buy tokens for `newBuyPrice` eth and sell tokens for `newSellPrice` eth
    /// @param newSellPrice Price the users can sell to the contract
    /// @param newBuyPrice Price users can buy from the contract
    function setPrices(uint256 newSellPrice, uint256 newBuyPrice) onlyOwner public {
        sellPrice = newSellPrice;
        buyPrice = newBuyPrice;
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
     *
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burn(uint256 _value) onlyOwner public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[this] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[this] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
        //totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(this, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
     *
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) onlyOwner public {
        _transfer(this, _to, _value);
    }

    /// @notice Buy tokens from contract by sending ether
    function () payable public {

        //this is minimum what you can buy
        require(msg.value >= 1 / buyPrice);

        //ICO has to be active
        require(now < endTime);

        //get amount of tokens to send to the seller
        uint amount = calculateAmount(msg.value);
        uint bonus = getBonus(amount);

        _transfer(this, msg.sender,  amount + bonus);
    }

    /**
     * Get bonus for Xmas and New Year
     */
    function getBonus(uint _amount) constant private returns (uint256) {
        if((now >= xmasStart && now <= xmasEnd) || (now >= newyearStart && now <= newyearEnd)) {
            return _amount * 50 / 100;
        }  else {
            return 0;
        }


    }

    /**
     * Calculate how mush XYZ you need to send
     */
    function calculateAmount(uint _amount) constant private returns (uint256) {
        //phase 1 (10 days)
        if(now >= phaseOneStart && now <= phaseOneEnd) {
            // calculates the amount
            return _amount * buyPrice + (_amount * buyPrice * 50 / 100);
        } 
        //phase 2 (15 days)
        else if (now >= phaseTwoStart && now <= phaseTwoEnd) {
            return _amount * buyPrice;
        } 
        //phase 3 (20 days)
        else {
            return _amount * buyPrice - (_amount * buyPrice * 50 / 100);
        }
    }

    /// @notice Sell `amount` tokens to contract
    /// @param amount amount of tokens to be sold
    function sell(uint256 amount) public {
        require(this.balance >= amount * sellPrice);      // checks if the contract has enough ether to buy
        _transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);              // makes the transfers
        msg.sender.transfer(amount * sellPrice);          // sends ether to the seller. It's important to do this last to avoid recursion attacks
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `msg.value` contains an amount in `wei`, not an amount in `Ether`.

`1 Ether` is equal to `1000000000000000000 wei`, so if you send `1 ether` to your function the value of `msg.value` will be `1000000000000000000`.

You might want something like this:

`require(msg.value >= 1 ether / buyPrice);`

The `ether` keyword in Solidity means '*multiply by 1000000000000000000* '.

I don't know why you are getting different results on Ropsten and Mainnet. They should function exactly the same way; you should get the exact same result if the contracts are in the same state and if the function calls are identical.

Please share the transaction ID's of your Ropsten and Mainnet transactions, then I can compare them and see what exactly happened differently.

Comment: I'm getting different results on Ropsten and Remix. I'll try this, thank you

Comment: @FosAvance Please share the transaction ID's of your Ropsten and Mainnet transactions, then I can compare them and see what exactly happened differently.

Comment: I haven't tried on Mainnet yet

Answer (score 3):

Solidity doesn't have floating point numbers

```
uint buyPrice = 100;
require(1 / buyPrice == 0);
```

Without the code I can't say why it failed in remix.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: It didn't fail in Remix, transaction didn't go through which means the logic worked. If it doesn't have floating numbers, how should I handle that?

Comment: @FosAvance Usually in Solidity programming, integer math is all you need. Neither tokens nor Ether itself ever use floating points to store amounts. It's all integers. The `.` you see in an amount is just a visual representation to make huge integers more readable.

Comment: I get it, thanks. But what about division? There has to be floating point there

Comment: No, there's not either. Numbers will get rounded down.